# How to list files from Dataset object in Azure Pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to list files from `Dataset` in Azure pipeline (build) but getting error, I tried below two ways

**Method #1**

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset
import os

ws = Workspace.from_config()
dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, "<dataset-name>")

print(os.listdir(str(dataset.as_mount())))
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '<azureml.data.dataset_consumption_config.DatasetConsumptionConfig
> object at >'

**Method #2**

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset
import os

ws = Workspace.from_config()
dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, "<dataset-name>")

data = dataset.mount()
data.start()
print(os.listdir(data.mount_point))
```

> Error: Mount is only supported on Unix or Unix-like operating systems
> with the native package libfuse installed.

Can anyone please help me with this, I am stuck at it from sometime.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.filedataset?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-data-filedataset-as-mount

Comment: @Shmack `print(os.listdir(dataset.as_mount())` throws error `TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike, integer or None, not DatasetConsumptionConfig`

Comment: `.as_mount()` has the path_on_compute keyword argument -> "The target path on the compute to make the data available at." Maybe you need to set that path and then you could `listdir`.

Comment: I was reading their docs: Create a Datastore `Datastore(workspace, name=None)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.datastore(class)?view=azure-ml-py. Create a DataPath  with the created datastore `DataPath(datastore=None, path_on_datastore=None, name=None)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.datapath.datapath?view=azure-ml-py#constructor. https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-showcasing-datapath-and-pipelineparameter.ipynb

Comment: IDK, this is the only other thing I found -> https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-showcasing-datapath-and-pipelineparameter.ipynb

Comment: Do you mean no issue pop out wen run the code on local? From your second situation, it seems you need to install libfuse, please [follow the docuement to install](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse#installation). And if you can run the code no problem on local, what about using [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install), this will make your pipeline run on the same environment as local.